# LEA parameters are wrong

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I wrote these lines:

```
num1 dw 7
num1_ptr dw 0
num1_ptr_ptr dw 0
lea num1_ptr, num1
lea num1_ptr_ptr, num1_ptr
mov bx, num1_ptr_ptr
mov bx, [bx]
mov ax, [bx]
call printNum ;printNum is 100% working. it prints the number in ax.
```

the problem is that the compiler says that the two lea instructions have wrong parameters. does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible forms of [`lea`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LEA.html) are

```
lea r16, mem
lea r32, mem
lea r64, mem
```

Despite being a CISC, x86 has a limited list of mem-to-mem instructions and `lea mem, mem` isn't on that list.

You can get rid of the *lea-nonsense* by simply initializing your data

```
num1           dw 7
num1_ptr       dw num1
num1_ptr_ptr   dw num1_ptr
```

Also, you are missing one dereference if you want to print `num1`.

Comment: its a school assignment so i have to initialize the pointers with 0 and use lea on the pointers so it will print num1 at the end.

Comment: @GuyShilman You can use a scratch register and then store its value: `lea ax, num1`/`mov [num1_ptr], ax` (and the same for the other pointer). Note that there is no real use for `lea` here, a more idiomatic `mov ax, OFFSET num1` (or `mov ax, num1` on NASM) will do.

Comment: Also, LEA with a source addressing mode not involving any registers is pointless.  (Except in 64-bit code with a RIP-relative addressing mode.)  In 16 and 32-bit code, you should always prefer `mov reg, OFFSET foo` (MASM) or `mov reg, foo` (NASM) over `lea reg, [disp32]` which is 1 byte longer.  Or in this case, `mov word ptr [num1_ptr], OFFSET num1` would work totally fine.  But static initializers are even better than runtime immediate stores.